# How to evaluate the closed form for $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\mathrm dx\over \sin^2(x)}\ln\left({a+b\sin^2(x)\over a-b\sin^2(x)}\right)=\pi\cdot F(a,b)?$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

Proposed:

> $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\mathrm dx\over \sin^2(x)}\ln\left({a+b\sin^2(x)\over a-b\sin^2(x)}\right)=\pi\cdot F(a,b)\tag1$$
>   Where $a\ge b$

Examples:

Where $F(1,1)= \sqrt{2}$, $F(2,1)=\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}$, $F(3,1)={1\over \sqrt{3}}(2-\sqrt{2})$, $...$

**How do we evaluate the closed form for $(1)?$**

Comment: $F(1,1) = \sqrt{2}$ not $\pi  \sqrt{2}$ since the $\pi$ is already present in equation (1).

Comment: Integration by parts works: just observe that $[\cot x]'=-\sin^{-2} x$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $u=\cot{x}$. Then $du = dx/\sin^2{x}$ and $\sin^2{x}=1/(1+u^2)$, and the limits become $\infty$ and $0$, so the integral becomes
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \log{\left( \frac{a+b/(1+u^2)}{a-b/(1+u^2)} \right)} \, du = \int_0^{\infty} \log{\left( \frac{a+b+au^2}{a-b+au^2} \right)}  du $$
One can now integrate this by parts to get a couple of easy rational integrals, although we should be a bit careful about the upper limit:
$$ \int_0^{M} \log{\left( \frac{a+b+au^2}{a-b+au^2} \right)}  du = \left[  u\log{\left( \frac{a+b+au^2}{a-b+au^2} \right)} \right]_0^M - \int_0^M u \left( \frac{2au}{a+b+au^2}-\frac{2au}{a-b+au^2} \right) du $$
The boundary term disappears: the bottom limit is clear, and the top limit follows because
$$ M\log{(a+(a+b)M^{-2})} - M\log{(a+(a-b)M^{-2})} \sim \frac{2b}{aM} \to 0 $$
as $M \to \infty$. The remaining integral is just a rational function; some partial fractions trickery lets us rewrite it as
$$  \int_0^M \left( \frac{2(a+b)}{a+b+au^2}-\frac{2(a-b)}{a-b+au^2} \right) du, $$
which we can then use the arctangent integral on to find the final answer
$$ \left( \sqrt{1+\frac{b}{a}} - \sqrt{1-\frac{b}{a}} \right)\pi $$
or
$$ \frac{\sqrt{a+b}-\sqrt{a-b}}{\sqrt{a}}\pi $$
or
$$ \frac{2b\pi}{\sqrt{a(a+b)}+\sqrt{a(a-b)}}, $$
depending on preference.

Answer (score 7):

You may like this method. Let 
$$I(b)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\mathrm dx\over \sin^2(x)}\ln\left({a+b\sin^2(x)\over a-b\sin^2(x)}\right) $$
and then
\begin{eqnarray}
I'(b)&=&\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\bigg(\frac1{a+b\sin^2(x)}+\frac1{a-b\sin^2(x)}\bigg) \mathrm dx\\
&=&\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt a}(\frac1{\sqrt{a+b}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a-b}}).
\end{eqnarray}
So
$$ I(b)=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{a}}\int_0^b(\frac1{\sqrt{a+t}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a-t}})dt=\pi\frac{\sqrt{a+b}-\sqrt{a-b}}{\sqrt a}$$
and hence
$$　F(a,b)=\frac{\sqrt{a+b}-\sqrt{a-b}}{\sqrt a}. $$

Comment: I do (+1)! Nice technique.

Answer (score 2):

The closed form you are looking for is
$$
F(a,b) = \sqrt{\frac{a+b}{a}}-\sqrt{\frac{a-b}{a}}
$$
This was hidden because for $F(2,1)$
$$
\left(\sqrt{\frac32}-\sqrt{\frac12}\right)^2 = 2-\sqrt{3}
$$
so the answer $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}$ is correct, but it is not in that uniform form.